# How can I integrate Salesforce with social networking sites like Facebook, Twitter, Google, etc

Tags: servicecloud

I recently read an article in Salesforce related to Service Cloud, where it talks about Driving Productivity with Service cloud.

In that article they have mentioned about Community networking websites:
"Community Networking websites help customers get timely support and solutions. Salesforce connects to where your customers are today: Google, Twitter, and Facebook. And Radian6 helps you automate social monitoring and integrate with customer service processes to provide closed loop follow up with your customers who participate in those social media communities"

**My question:**
Can someone tell me in what way I could integrate Facebook, Twitter etc. with Salesforce. At this point I don't need to know how to setup these integrations, but just need to know in what ways/forms or how the customers can use this integration to communicate with Salesforce.

Comment: Would be nice if you were to upvote some of the answers to this question!

Answer (score 10):

It really depends on the level of integration that you want and what you want to monitor from social media.

The Salesforce for Twitter and Facebook application from the app exchange allows you to automatically create cases when someone @mentions you on twitter or when someone posts to your facebook page. This is a free application.

Radian6 is has considerably more monitoring capability (keywords related to your brand, for example) and is also pretty good at identifying sentiment (for example, whether the post is a compliment or a rant!).  You can integrate this with Salesforce via the Social Hub which is highly configurable.  However, Radian6 is a paid application and is not cheap.

There are other applications that integrate with Salesforce as well - Sprout Social for example (http://sproutsocial.com/features/social-media-crm) - but I haven't used those so I don't know how well they integrate with Salesforce.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The way that this site works is that if the answer is correct you would upvote it and accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for Janrain, which is a Social Sign-on for Salesforce, check out the following link : [how to](http://janrain.com/blog/how-to-set-up-salesforce-site-with-janrain-engage/)
I tested myself and it's working really well. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Look at the Appexchange app Twitter for Salesforce.  It lets you connect to Twitter and FB to capture cases via tweets and post to FB fan pages.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a new feature in Spring '14: Social Accounts, Contacts, and Leads:

> Salesforce1 users can now leverage the power of social media to
>   connect with their accounts, contacts, and leads.
>
> Starting in Spring
>   ‘14, you can find and link to Twitter profiles, and view Twitter
>   profile images, Tweets, and followers for your accounts, contacts, and
>   leads with Salesforce1. And, use the new People in Common feature to
>   discover shared connections.

- [Release note](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_sales_social_twitter_in_sfdc1.htm)
- [Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=contacts_social_enable.htm&language=en)